# java get which day of month from ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I want to find out which day of month from a given `ZonedDateTime`.
I know the day is Thursday and want to find which Thursday of month?
For example:

- 2021-06-10T13:30:30+03:00  is 2. Thursday;
- 2021-06-17T13:30:30+03:00  is 3. Thursday;
- 2021-06-24T13:30:30+03:00  is last Thursday;
- etc.

  ```
  private static int getWhicDayOfMonth(ZonedDateTime date) {

  }
  ```

What is the easy way to do this?

Comment: *day of month* means 1st, 2nd or 28th of a month... Are you asking for something like *weekday of month*? The easiest way to get the *day of month* would be to `return date.getDayOfMonth()`...

Comment: i didn't mean it. day of month means: i know that day is Thursday but i want to find which Thursday in that month (1st, 2nd.. or last).

Comment: reposting because parantheses were wrong: i would assume integer division by 7 will solve this? `(dayOfMonth - 1) // 7 + 1` - if it is 1, it is the first week and so on. Of course "last" requires more effort than that, but since you asked for `int`, I think you can figure it out in a different method.

Comment: The answer of @thinkgruen is the easiest and should be the accepted one. Days `1 - 7` in a month are ALWAYS the 1st of their respective DayOfWeek, `8 - 14` ALWAYS the 2nd an so on. It doesnt matter at all which DayOfWeek was the first of a month and it doesn't matter which DayOfWeek it is today. You dont have to count anything. Its a simple mathematical calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private static int getWhicDayOfMonth(ZonedDateTime date) {
    return (date.getDayOfMonth() - 1) / 7 + 1;
 }
```

In your examples:

```
10 -> 2
17 -> 3
24 -> 4
31 (in some months) -> 5
```

alternatively simplify to `date.getDayOfMonth() + 6) / 7` - but i tend to find this more confusing to read

Comment: additionally, if you want to see if something is "last", you need to check if there are less than 7 days to the end of the month.

Comment: Nice approach... +1 for brevity

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the first occurrence of the day-of-the-week in the month, loop through all days of the month with a step value of 7 days and keep incrementing the counter until the given date is matched.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(whichDowOfTheMonth("2021-06-10T13:30:30+03:00"));
        System.out.println(whichDowOfTheMonth("2021-06-17T13:30:30+03:00"));
        System.out.println(whichDowOfTheMonth("2021-06-24T13:30:30+03:00"));
    }

    static int whichDowOfTheMonth(String strDateTime) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek();

        ZonedDateTime zdtFirstDowOfMonth = zdt.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(dow));
        ZonedDateTime zdtLastDayOfMonth = zdt.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());

        int count = 1;
        for (ZonedDateTime date = zdtFirstDowOfMonth; !date.isAfter(zdtLastDayOfMonth); date = date.plusDays(7)) {
            if (date.equals(zdt))
                break;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
4
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PTLJwf)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same approach as in the answer provided by @ArvindKumarAvinash, but looping is a little different:

```java
/**
 * <p>
 * Calculates which weekday of the month it is
 * in the {@link ZonedDateTime} passed.
 * </p>
 *  
 * @param zonedDateTime the datetime to calculate its "weekday of month"
 * @return the weekday of month
 */
private static int getWeekdayOfMonth(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
    // extract the values you are interested in from the datetime passed
    int dayOfMonth = zonedDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zonedDateTime.getDayOfWeek();
    // provide a counter variable
    int weekdayCount = 0;
    // then iterate until the day of month and compare the days of week
    for (int d = 1; d <= dayOfMonth; d++) {
        if (zonedDateTime.withDayOfMonth(d).getDayOfWeek() == dayOfWeek) {
            // increase counter at every match (including the one passed)
            weekdayCount++;
        }
    }
    
    return weekdayCount;
}
```

You could use it like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZonedDateTime zdt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-06-17T13:30:30+03:00")
                                      .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(
                                                             "Europe/Istanbul"
                                                         )
                                      );
    System.out.println("The date "
                    + zdt.toLocalDate()
                    + " is "
                    + zdt.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)
                    + " no. "
                    + getWeekdayOfMonth(zdt)
                    + " in "
                    + zdt.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
}
```

and receive the response

```
The date 2021-06-17 is Thursday no. 3 in June
```

in your console.